# Access to third party website content from non-whitelist IP address

Tags: java, php, apache-httpclient-4.x

University website needs to provide access to documents hosted on third party website which allows only whitelisted IP addresses, university server address being one of them.
The issue is that the university website( say myyniversity.com) provides an href list to other third party websites. Once a logged in student clicks on the link from any public network, the browser domain changes to the third party content provider(say thirdparty.com). Thirdparty.com has a list of the documents. The user clicks on a link and his IP address is exposed which is not the whitelist. So access is denied.

We need a solution for this. 
VPN is not on plate as we can't invest that much.